# MySQL relational databases with large dataset?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to access data from two tables that share a common 'SpeciesName' field.

Table 'coords' is a very large dataset with over 5500 entries, and the table itself has around 26 fields.  The Unique ID of this table is the Matrix Number, which runs from 0-5500, and each row contains slightly unique data. There are multiple rows with the same 'SpeciesName', however - there are only 446 unique 'SpeciesNames' within the table.

Table 'common' stores common name and image data for each 'SpeciesNames' with 3 fields. Basically what I am trying to do it set up a MySQL relation between the two tables using 'SpeciesNames' as the foreign key and access the data from both in one query.

Where to start? Google searches have yielded results dealing with tables containing one or two fields.  However when I query, I want to select ALL fields from BOTH tables in PHP. Any advice regarding this would be wonderful.

Edit:
I know the data isn't large at the moment, but it will be! I should have been clearer about that. This is 'coords':

```
`Authors` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Journal` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YearPublication` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOIISBN` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdditionalSource` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ecoregion` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrowthType` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GrowthFormRaunkiaer` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumberPopulations` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnnualPeriodicity` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CriteriaSize` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CriteriaOntogeny` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CriteriaAge` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Kingdom` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phylum` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AngioGymno` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DicotMonoc` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `_Order` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Family` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Genus` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SpeciesName` varchar(500) DEFAULT 'NA',
  `EnteredBy` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EnteredDate` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Source` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SpeciesAuthor` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StudiedSex` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixComposite` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixTreatment` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixCaptivity` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixStartYear` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixStartSeason` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixStartMonth` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixEndYear` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixEndSeason` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixEndMonth` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Population` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatDeg` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatMin` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatSec` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LonDeg` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LonMin` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LonSec` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LatitudeDec` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LongitudeDec` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Altitude` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Continent` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixSplit` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Observation` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MatrixClassOrganized` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Matrixnumber` varchar(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MatrixClassNumber` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dimension` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plantType` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matrix` varchar(15000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `_ClassNames` varchar(16000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatusStudy` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatusStudyRef` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatusElsewhere` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatusElsewhereRef` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Matrixnumber`),
```

And 'common':

```
  `ID` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `CommonName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ImageUrl` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `UploadImgUrl` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `SpeciesAccepted` (`ID`),
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
```

I'm basically plotting each record on a map using the coordinates and displaying all of the information from 'coords'- this has already been achieved successfully. The table 'common' contains new information that has been dynamically created for each 'SpeciesName' (coords.SpeciesName and common.ID), so I would like to display the CommonName and utilise the 'ImageUrl' and 'UploadedImgUrl' alongside the data I previously had.  I'm still a bit of a newbie to MySQL, so I apologise if my terminology isn't perfect!

Comment: 5500 records is not large. Your problem/situation is not really clear to me, but I think you need a many to many relationship.

Comment: belive me 5500 is very very small size for mysql :) for example the table which I working now has about 7(seven) million rows.

Comment: @Peter its growing every day, want to ensure it works with larger amounts of records, no matter what size it grows to, considering the nature of the data. It needs to be able to expand and I want to insure against the future!

Comment: If thousands of of data sets is large for mysql, MYSQL would have been rubbish, and wouldn't be so popular as it  is today.That is very small data sets.

Comment: Show some data!!! 10 million rows isn't that big.. 5500 is small... we need to see the table structure and some data to help you

Comment: Millions of records in a table isn't an issue for MySQL as long as you have set indexes appropriate to the queries that you execute

Comment: Start by reading about `JOIN` operators.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The basic idea is to avoid having redundant data in a table and instead only keep a single value (SpeciesNames in your case) to which you reference.

So instead of having `coords.SpeciesName`, which contains the same string as `common.CommonName` you would store a reference as `coords.SpeciesName_id` which stores the `common.ID`. Both fields should be of type `INT` for perfomance resons, since they can be compared much quicker than strings.

To fetch data from both tables in a single query, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM coords JOIN common ON coords.SpeciesName_id = common.ID
```

A quick search on google yields this [intro to normalization](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html), for example.

Another search for [PHP MySQL tutorial](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP%20MySQL%20tutorial) will give you hints on how to execute the query using PHP.

Comment: andy from what i understood from the OP's question its dealing with matrix's which sometimes need redundant data..

Comment: From what I understand, OP wants to remove redundant SpeciesName entries. Of course, it is not always desirable to remove all redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with MYSQL is not the database size or records number! I've seen database files up to 10-12 GB. The main problem my occur when you want to fetch the records and you may face the problem in number of queries you can handle at a time! if you pay attention in the way you perform your queries no serious problem will happen.